# Router cannot route when click an item

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have an issue with Routing when I click an item in list-item component, it can not route to detail-component. Below is my source:

**product-list.component.html:**

```
<h1>Product List Component</h1>
<ul class="products">
   <li *ngFor="let product of products">
      <a routerLink="/detail/{{product.id}}">
         <span class="badge">{{product.id}}</span> {{product.name}}
      </a>
   </li>
</ul>
```

**product-detail.component.ts**

```
export class ProductDetailComponent implements OnInit {

   constructor(
      private route: ActivatedRoute,
      private productService: ProductService
   ) { }

   ngOnInit() {
      this.getProduct();
   }

   private getProduct(): void {
      const id = +this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
      this.productService.getProductById(id);
   }

}
```

**product-detail.component.html:**

```
<p>Just one line to test routing to this component</p>
```

**ProductService.ts**

```
@Injectable({
   providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ProductService {

   constructor() { }

   getAllProduct(): Product[] {
      return arrayProduct;
   }

   getProductById(id: number): Product {
      const product = arrayProduct.find(product => product.id === id);
      return product;
   }

}
```

**Router**

```
const routes: Routes = [
   { path: 'detail/:id', component: ProductDetailComponent }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

**Below is the image view of the list-item component**
[image: View of list-item component]

Anyone can help me, please! Thank you so much.

Comment: do you get any errors in the console?

Comment: a stackblitz example is always welcome to show us your problem :)

Answer (score 1):

I believe you don't use router link as it should be

try something like this :

```
<h1>Product List Component</h1>
<ul class="products">
   <li *ngFor="let product of products">
      <a [routerLink]="['/detail/',product.id]">
         <span class="badge">{{product.id}}</span> {{product.name}}
      </a>
   </li>
</ul>
```

It's because you don't use correctly the routerLink directive

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing here is wrong

```
<h1>Product List Component</h1>
<ul class="products">
   <li *ngFor="let product of products">
      <a routerLink="/detail/{{product.id}}">
         <span class="badge">{{product.id}}</span> {{product.name}}
      </a>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Change
 `<a routerLink="/detail/{{product.id}}">` 
to

`<a [routerLink]="['/detail/',product.id]">`

then it will invoke the route correctly. The `routerlink` has to be inside square brackets. like this :- `[routerLink]="['YOUR ROUTE HERE']"` Also I assume you have added the routing module to the relevent app.module.ts too.

Comment: Well it was mostly for routeLink :) you're welcome  @SelakaN !

Comment: Router link doesnt have to be inside square brackets: https://angular.io/guide/router#router-links

Comment: Yes but in this case he is passing value to the controller right? Then it should be in property binding state right?